# grouping similar values of y and getting the x values - using octave / matlab

Tags: grouping, categories, octave

I have imported a voice audio signal and I'm trying to find all the values of **t** (the time line) along with their indexes where **yy2** (the audio signal) values are similar.

I can group **yy2** values using `histc` but how can I get it so that I know the values of **t** for the grouped **yy2** values?

Should I be using `histc` for this since the bins (total bars used in the plot) will be more than 10?

My thoughts where to:

1. to group similar values of **yy2**.
2. get the **t** values for each grouped **yy2** value that is similar.

**In the code below, yy2 simulates the imported audio signal**.

```
clear, clc, clf,close all

pkg load signal

fs_rate=8000
len_of_sig=1.5; %length of signal in seconds
t=linspace(0,len_of_sig,fs_rate*len_of_sig);
yy2=.5*sin(2*pi*3*t)+.3*sin(2*pi*2.2*t);

subplot(2,1,1);plot(t,yy2,'-*');
subplot(2,1,2);hist(yy2)
```

plot:
[image: Plot]

Ps:  I'm using Octave 4.2.2 which is similar to matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want groups of indices and values of `t` where `yy2` values are similar:

```
% Get uniqe valuse of yy2
unique_vals = unique(yy2);

% Get index groups for each unique yy2 value in a cell array
index_groups = arrayfun(@(v) find((yy2 == v)),unique_vals,'UniformOutput',false);

% Get t groups for each unique yy2 value in a cell array
t_groups = cellfun(@(v) t(v),index_groups,'UniformOutput',false);

% Get yy2 groups for each unique yy2 value in a cell array (not really required)
yy2_groups = cellfun(@(v) yy2(v),index_groups,'UniformOutput',false);
```